# Restler optional string parameter

Tags: php, restler

I want to mark a parameter as optional in a Restler patch method, and it's of type string, but I can't figure out how to do this.  If I put `$description = null` as the parameter then the router is failing with a message saying `description` is a required parameter.

I can't just use an empty string either becuase this is a PATCH type method, so I have to be able to differentiate between them wanting to blank out the description by passing an empty string vs. a null value meaning they didn't pass in any update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keeping `$description` to `null` works fine. Just make sure all optional parameters appear after required parameters in your api method. This is a php restriction.

#### Here is how I have tested it

```
composer create-project restler/application=dev-basic rest
```

To create a basic restler project. Then edited rest/src/Home.php to add the patch method

```
<?php

class Home
{
    public function index()
    {
        return [
            'success' => [
                'code'    => 200,
                'message' => 'Restler is up and running!',
            ],
        ];
    }

    public function patch($name, $description = null)
    {
        return compact('name', 'description');
    }
}
```

Started the web server using `php serve` on the command line. Launched the explorer with http://localhost/explorer and then tested the patch method with the following json

```
{
  "name": "arul"
}
```

The api result is

```
{
  "name": "arul",
  "description": null
}
```

Which is the expected result

Comment: Thanks, Arul.  I had erroneously added non-optional parameters after this one.  Your reminder about that PHP requirement solved my issue.